# How to avoid this issue is EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this text issue in the second editText under "state address" in the following image :

[image]

As you can see the text is shifted up ... only the bottom part of it is almost visible ... I created this edittext pragmatically by copying all the properties of the first editText under "state address" then adding it to the parent linearLayout using addView() method.

this is the code :

```
EditText addMore = new EditText(this);
    EditText old = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    addMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.glow_edittext);
    addMore.setLayoutParams(old.getLayoutParams());
    addMore.setHeight(old.getHeight());
    addMore.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    parent.addView(addMore);
```

This is the XML code for the EditText whose attributes are to be copied :

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/serviceAddressEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/glow_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text|textPostalAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >

    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is use an `inflater` and put the `editText` in an external layout file:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edittext_glow, null);
parent.addView(v);
```

That way you are sure all attributes are set the way you want. It is likely you missed an attribute (like the font-size) but we can not know because you did not provide the xml of the working `editText`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... i will try it out ... you may also want to check the edit for the XML.